# Meaning of "It is due to my mistress to say of her"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

Excerpted from *LEARNING TO READ* by *Frederick Douglass*

> I  lived  in  Master  Hugh's  family  about  seven  years.  During  this  time,  I  succeeded  in  learning  to  read  and  write.  In  accomplishing  this,  I  was  compelled  to  resort  to  various  stratagems. I had no regular teacher. My mistress, who had kindly commenced to instruct  me,  had,  in  compliance  with  the  advice  and  direction  of  her  husband,  not  only  ceased  to  instruct,  but  had  set  her  face  against  my  being  instructed  by  anyone  else.  **It  is  due,  however,  to  my  mistress  to  say  of  her,  that  she  did  not  adopt  this  course  of  treatment  immediately.**  She  at  first  lacked  the  depravity  indispensable  to  shutting  me  up  in  mental  darkness.  It  was  at  least  necessary  for  her  to  have  some  training  in  the  exercise  of  irresponsible  power,  to  make  her  equal  to  the  task  of  treating  me  as  though  I  were  a  brute.

What does the bolded sentence mean? I can't understand its structure, *It is due to my mistress to say of her*?, it's odd.

Comment: *Due* here has its old sense of *owing*: I owe it her to say X, she deserves this acknowledgment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Due* here is of its old sense, meaning *owing*. So the sentence mean the mistress deserves a fair description, that she is not like this at first.